# My modal show all elements at same time. I just want one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I want my modal to show one element for a period of time, but my modal will show all elements at the same time when I click a button element. How I could do this in a dynamic way?

#### jquery:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("show");
})
```

#### jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jx8Ch/1/

How do I make them work separately?

Comment: what exact u want? like u want to show only image on 1st click and then description on 2nd click?

Comment: I've updated your jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jx8Ch/4/

Answer (score 1):

Replace the word '`body`' with the element that you want to show/hide when the button is clicked.  For example, 
`$('img').toggleClass('show') or $('h2').toggleClass('show')`.

Better yet, give that element a class or an id and then refer to it that way.  For example, `$('.your_class_name').toggleClass('show') or $('#your_id').toggleClass('show');`

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you so far! :D i dont know if u understand me.. i want to make this a more dinamically. i want to put html only, without make changes in jquery all the time